# No provider for http client Ionic 3 error

Tags: ionic-framework

i've been trying to fix this for some hours now. My ionic app while running keeps bringing this error 'No provider for http client'. i have added a HttpModule and also included it in imports f my app.module.ts but still get this dreaded error.
[image: error of ionic app]

[image: my app.module.ts code]

```html
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { WeatherProvider } from '../providers/weather/weather';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpModule,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    WeatherProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually Discovered that i was including 'httpModule'instead of 'httpClient' .

i fixed it by replacing it in my code

```html
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { WeatherProvider } from '../providers/weather/weather';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClient,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    WeatherProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```